# Return the name of a single disk

Tags: vb.net

get one drive pc
just drive ( D:\ )

```
For Each x In IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives
                MsgBox(x.Name)
Next
```

its get all :/
i need get just ( D:\ ) 
if pc not have ( D:\ ) it will get next drive ( E:\ )

Comment: Are there any other criteria for the last drive, or does `IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives.Last()` return what you need?

Comment: I will explain more to you
In my pc there are 3 drives
C:\
D:\
E:\

first request:  I want to get only D:\

In my friend's pc he only has
C:\
E:\

second request:   I want my program to get E:\ if it can not find D:\

Comment: i have error! 'ToList' is not a member of 'System.Array'.

Comment: i already used Imports System.IO and this error not hide :/

Comment: my code it true

Comment: For Each x In IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives : MsgBox(x.Name) :Next              this get all drives i need get just D:\ drive

Comment: ok i used MsgBox(DriveInfo.GetDrives()(1).Name)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions. Write in complete sentences as well!

Answer (score -1):

```
MsgBox(DriveInfo.GetDrives()(1).Name)
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions, because this is not one.